# multiple NVL parameters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below query

```
where username=NVL('&XID',username);
```

Above query work well with single '*XID*' values

But suppose I have to enter multiple *XID* values, Then how my query should be ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `coalesce`:

```
WHERE username = COALESCE('&XID1', '&XID2', '&XID3', username)
```

Comment: Actually there are 3 input parameter as below.---POSTDATE between to_date('&START_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') and to_date('&END_DATE','DD-MM-YYYY') and username=NVL('&XID',username);

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce`. It will return the first non null value of the values introduced in it

```
where username= coalesce('value1', 'value2', 'value3', username)
```

Comment: But my username is not fixed.. It may be 1-2-3.... or N numbers of username

Comment: @RakeshWarang Then how do you decide which username should be passed if the preceding values are null?

Comment: -if the preceding values are null,i will enter specific usernames as per my requirements, it may be 1 to n th usernames & If i only enter , it will give data of all usernames for that specific period